# Create Dynamic HTML Pages with Drupal Theme

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, themes

I am New to Drupal and have setup a base Drupal site with a Theme.

I would like to create some external pages outside of the Drupal CMS but use the same Drupal Theme of the rest of my website - so I get the same look and feel.

Would you suggest I go down this path of creating external PHP pages surrounded by the Drupal Theme, OR is there an alternative to creating dynamic pages in Drupal.

I want to create pages that have nearly the same data but for different cities around the world. If I did this manually in Drupal - it would take forever to create and manage. So I want to just use .htaccess to rewrite the page.

eg.
USA/Miami
USA/LA
UK/London
UK/Birmingham
Australia/Melbourne
Australia/Sydney
etc.

I have started to create a new PHP page by copying over some of the .tpl tags of the theme, and including css files, but I don't get the Header/Footer data.

Bascially I want to know how to create an external page using the Drupal theme's look and feel for the Header/Footer/Body and use my own data for the Content area.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help, but dont know what you exactly mean. In general Drupal is mostly (if not only) about dynamic content, that can be perfectly managed without creating additional templates. For example, you could use the smart Ip module https://drupal.org/project/smart_ip , that provides the ability to make database queries and custom content reprensentations (via views https://drupal.org/project/views). Then you present the corresponding display to the user based on his location.
Maybe this suggestion is totally off-point - thusly:

Could you post the .htaccess solution and as well the original template and one of the modified (per city, country), because I am not quite clear what the approach and indeed the demands are.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jojomojo. I've had a bit of a play around with Drupal now and have found that you can create Custom Content Types tied to their own Custom Template. So I'll use this with perhaps some PHP code in the template file. Still got lots more learning to do I guess but I think i'll figure it out.